# How to use variable's value instead of it's identifier?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, input

I'm making a program to output the scientific name of specific fruits from input. This is my source:

```
import time;

fruits={
    "apple":"Malus domestica",
    "banana":"Musa acuminata",
    "orange":"Citrus sinensis",
    "lychee":"Litchi chinensis",
};

fruit=input("Enter a fruit(either an apple, banana, orange, or lychee):");

if fruit in fruits:
    print("Your fruit's scientific name is "+fruits.fruit+"\n");
else:
    print("Sorry, the fruit you entered was not in the database");
```

But when I enter "orange" as my input into the console, the compiler throws an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fruit'
>
```

Is there any way to use the value of "fruit" rather than use it as a dict element?

Comment: "Is there any way to use the value of "fruit" rather than use it as a dict element?" - what? But you *have* a dict, and what you *need* is dict indexing. Why are you asking how to do the wrong thing? If you get what you're asking for and retrieve the attribute named `orange` instead of `fruit`, you'll just get a different `AttributeError`.

Comment: Also you don't need to add the `\n` manually - `print` does that itself unless you tell it not to - and Python doesn't require `;` at the end of a statement.

Comment: Change `fruits.fruit` to `fruits[fruit]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]`:

```py
print(f"Your fruit's scientific name is {fruits[fruit]}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your code from this:

```
if fruit in fruits:
    print("Your fruit's scientific name is "+fruits.fruit+"\n");
```

to this:

```
if fruit in fruits:
    print("Your fruit's scientific name is "+fruits[fruit]+"\n");
```